# Trouble using Sylow's theorems

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

[image]

So, I found part (a) fairly easy, and also managed part (c) assuming (b) to be true.

Any help with (d) and especially (b) would really be appreciated.

My issue with part (b) is understanding which of Sylow's theorems to apply and how. I tried first to apply part (a) to find that, since Sylow $p$-subgroups by definition are non trivial (have $p$ as a factor of their order), then $$1<S\leq K \implies N_K(S) = N_G(S).$$ I was hoping doing this would allow me to somehow apply Sylow's second theorem as conjugation naturally comes up in the problem, but I can not see how I would go about using it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For (b) let $P_0$ be a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $K$, and let $P$ be a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$ which contains $P_0$. Then $Z(P)$ normalises $P_0$ so by (a), with $Q=P_0$, we have that $Z(P)\leqslant K$. Now $P$ normalises $Z(P)$, so by (a), with $Q=Z(P)$, we have that $P\leqslant K$.

For (d), there are $|G:N(K)|=|G:K|$ conjugates of $K$. These don't overlap except in the identity, so together they contain $1+|G:K| (|K|-1)$ elements. This leaves $|G:K|-1$ outside.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am still a little lost however. When you are using (a) you seem to be deriving that Z(P) is a subgroup of K and that P is a subgroup of K, but the lemma only shows that if you have a non-trivial subgroup of K, then the normalisers of that subgroup in G and K are equal. Is the center of P (Z(P)) equal to the normaliser of P_0 in K?

Comment: The reasoning of @ancientmathematician is correct. Observe that (a) is equivalent to $N_G(Q) \subseteq K$. So $N_G(P_0) \subseteq K$. Also, since $P$ is a non-trivial $p$-group, $Z(P)$ is non-trivial. By the way, $K$ is a so-called Frobenius complement. Frobenius groups are thoroughly studied in the literature.

Comment: Thank you this answer really helped. One last thing: I don't understand why $|G:N(K)| = |G:K|$

Comment: Apply (a) to $K$.

Comment: I was thinking that, but is it necessarily the case that $N_K(K) = K$ then?

Comment: $K\leqslant N_G(K)=N_K(K)\leqslant K$ where the middle equality is by (a).