# Difficulty using Sylow theorems

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

[image]

I am really struggling to apply Sylow's theorems to various problems, so any help is much appreciated.

For part (a) here, since we are supposing that $H<G$, I tried to use an element $g$ of $G$ that is not in $H$ to find that $gH \neq Hg$ using that every element normalising $P$ is in $H$. I couldn't think of a way to do this.

I also tried to think of a way to prove it via the contrapositive (if $H$ is a proper normal subgroup of $G$, then $N_G(P)$ is not a subgroup of $H$. This also failed.

I am sure I should be using the Sylow theorems here but I can not tell how any of them can be applied in a useful way.

Comment: What text is this from?

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: [Your previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4069544/104041) had a very similar title.

Answer (score 0):

(a) Let $H$ be a normal in $G$. Then $H^x=H$ for every $x\in G$ and $P^x<H^x=H$. Since the subgroup $H$ has exactly one Sylow $p$-subgroup, it follows that $P^x=P$. So $x\in H$ and $H=G$. We have arrived at a contradiction.

Comment: We don't know that $H$ has exactly one Sylow $p$-subgroup. We have to use the fact that $P^x$ and $P$ are conjuagte by an element of $H$, so $P^{xy}=P$ with $y \in H$, hence $xy \in N_G(P) \le H \Rightarrow x \in H$.

Comment: You are right, of course. But a finite group has a unique Sylow p-subgroup P if and only if P is normal. This is a simple consequence of the fact that Sylow p-subgroups  are conjugate and the student should know it.